# WordPress fresh installation did not update default plugin and themes to latest version

Tags: plugins, themes, updates

im new here i have a couple question regarding wordpress. First of all i tried install wordpress latest version which is 5.4.2 and after finish installing and login to admin panel and found out that couple of default theme and plugin did not updated to the latest version. Is it by default wordpress did not updated it to the latest version?

Comment: The bundled plugins and themes will be the version that they were when that version of WordPress is released. New versions of WordPress aren’t created when updates are released for the bundled plugins and themes. They’ll just be rolled into the next version of WordPress.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. it's solved all my curiosity about that.